# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test_username' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I was following a tutorial on yt about checking if student_ID is already in the database, I copied the codes and used it instead on the username if it is already taken. Since i am new to ASP.NET C#, I dont know what I should be replacing in the code or taken out.

here is the code:

```
sqlCon.Open();
SqlCommand check_username = new SqlCommand("select ACC_NUM from USERS where ACC_NUM ='"+ Text_username.Text + "' ", sqlCon);
SqlDataAdapter SD = new SqlDataAdapter(check_username);
DataTable DT = new DataTable(); 
SD.Fill(DT);
if(DT.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Notificationtext.Text = "Username is already taken!";
}
```

here is the error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test_username' to data type int.

```
Line 29:                 SqlDataAdapter SD = new SqlDataAdapter(check_username);
Line 30:                 DataTable DT = new DataTable(); 
Line 31:                 SD.Fill(DT); 
Line 32:                 if(DT.Rows.Count > 0)
Line 33:                 {
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you *start* by using parameterized queries instead of embedding the value into the SQL itself. That will help with not just the conversion issues, but also avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Note that if you're using a tutorial that builds SQL like this, and doesn't scream in huge letters "this is really dangerous!" then I would find another tutorial *immediately*. (And if the tutorial is using unconventional variable names like this, that's another reason to find a better one. The earlier you get into the habit of following .NET naming conventions, the better. It's a shame that there are a lot of really bad tutorials around.)

Comment: Please use http://dapper-tutorial.net instead; it'll solve many problems and  prevent you wasting hours of your life having been misled into thinking that this tedious boilerplate is a reasonable way to do data access these days. DataTables are very old technology

Comment: As an aside, the root cause of your problem is that you've taken a tutorial that looks up a number in a database (acc_num is numeric), and only swapped half of it over to using a string for username. A number column will never contain "test_username". Your query would need to be more like `var r = connection.ExecuteScalar<int?>("SELECT acc_num FROM table WHERE acc_username = @u", new { u = Text_username.Text })` (Dapper syntax) and then inspect the result for being null. By looking up the ID this one query can serve both login (result needs to be a value) and reg (result needs to be null)

Comment: You are asking if a string: "Username" is equal to an account number, likely an int 32. 

That will never work. Resolve the username to an actual name, likely something you have defiend as a "var-char" or "nvarchar". 

SQL cannot infer that acccount_number from username. You must compare name to name.

Comment: (Alternatively, if you'll use other fields out of the table for login, you can do e.g. `var p = connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<Person>("SELECT * FROM person WHERE acc_username = @u", new { u = Text_username.Text })` then you have other fields of the person available so you can say e.g. `"Hello " + p.Name + " you last logged in on " + p.LastLoginDate` and so on.. and if youre trying to do a registration, you want the `p` to be null to assure the username isn't taken (no matching records)

Comment: Another issue you have here is that you need to dispose your connection and adapter objects with `using`. Also if you are just checking for existence of a row you could use `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: student_ID is of int type, please save numbers like 1,2,3, and then retrieve Test_username according to the ID when displayed